# Apply error handling in react google analytics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using `react-ga` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga) module in my React application, so that i can send events, to google analytics.

I have read the documentation of `react-ga` and i cant find a way to have a response after i send data to google analytics.

The way i m sending data is like so:

```
import *  ReactGA from 'react-ga'

  function sendEvent(category: string, action: string, label: string) {
    ReactGA.event({
      category,
      action,
      label,
    });
  }

  function sendPageView(title: string, url: string) {
    ReactGA.set({ page: title });
    ReactGA.send()
    ReactGA.pageview(url);
  }
```

These are just calls to google-analytics, without any feedback, What i m looking for is a function that get a **callback** OR an async function, that executes the above.

**POST request to google-analytics:**.

Actually, there is an automatic **POST**  request, each time i m sending an event, which fetches `1` on response.(***i dont control the POST request***)
The request is like so: `Request URL: https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?v=1&_v=...`.

**What i try to accomplish, is to catch Errors and send them to Sentry server:**.

- get errors, in case google analytics server is not responding
- get error, in case there is a timeout, on the response of google-analytics.com.

Possibly this module is restricted on functionality, has anyone else used something similar and managed to get any kind of Errors ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the case, based on the official google-analytics documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hitCallback

I attach the solutions, for reference:

1. Send an event and call the **callback function** when completed:

```
    ReactGA.ga('send', 'event', 'Page view' {
      hitCallback: (res: any) => {
        console.log('*** page view event success.');
        return true;
      },
    });
```

2. Send an event and time it to **1sec**.
   If the **callback** is not executed by then,  i raise a timeout error, otherwise i execute the success code:

```
 let alreadyCalled: boolean = false;
    function myCode(timeout: boolean, hasResponded: boolean) {
      if (alreadyCalled) return;

      alreadyCalled = true;

      if (timeout === true && hasResponded === false) {
        // TODO, THROW AN ERROR AND SEND TO SENTRY
        console.log('Time out error, sending message to Sentry..');
      } else if (timeout === false && hasResponded === true) {
        // TODO, send event success
        console.log('send event to google-analytics, success');
      }
    }

    ReactGA.ga('send', 'event', 'pageview', { hitCallback: () => myCode(false, true) });
    setTimeout(() => myCode(true, false), 10);
```

I hope it helps anyone that needs something similar.